# MySQL Stored Procedure that select, check dates and insert

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in MySQL. I have never used one so I don't even know if it's possibile to do what I need.

I have two tables :

1. the first contains jobs that are already done (id_operator, date,
   payment_days, payment_status..)
2. the second one contains the notifications that are sent to the
   operators (id, text, id_operator..)

I need to select all the records from the first table that have 0 in the payment_status field, check if the date + payment_days exceeds the current date and insert a notification in the other table with the id of the operator.

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: it's easier to understand only if you post your table schema.

Comment: That would require only one `INSERT ... SELECT` statement. Are you sure you want to use a procedure?

Comment: I need to execute it every 24h, the table schema is pretty big I don't think you need it

Comment: I'm not convinced that you need to store what is essentially derived data, but if you do, then Stav Ros's approach seems reasonable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
INSERT INTO notifications(text, id_operator)
SELECT 'notification text', id_operator
FROM jobs
WHERE payment_status = 0
  AND CURRENT_DATE <= DATE(DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL payment_days DAY));
```

Using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` you can select the results and insert them into another table.

Comment: If you swap the formula around then MySQL can use an index.